# Convert pem public key into ethereum address by Go

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, aws

I have ECC_SECG_P256K1 Public key PEM File generated by AWS KMS.

I want to convert pem public key into ethereum address by Go.

How can I get it?

Sample Pem Data

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEjgRz1kswP5KV4diFvYGegDVjeTIABq0a
82r4T41Wz94LDApF9OGyZsUSoQ59gaEVQark4mEQGQqV9HHQzlPavQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I tried this code.（x,y returned nil）

```
var pemData = []byte(`MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEjgRz1kswP5KV4diFvYGegDVjeTIABq0a82r4T41Wz94LDApF9OGyZsUSoQ59gaEVQark4mEQGQqV9HHQzlPavQ==`)
x,y := elliptic.UnmarshalCompressed(elliptic.P256(),pemData)
pubkey := elliptic.Marshal(secp256k1.S256(), x, y)
```

Comment: PEM certificates are quite complicated to parse. I'd recommend to look for a specific library to decode it. In javascript I'd use OpenPGPjs.

Answer (score 2):

If this key is generated by some of the supported curves by the default lib, you can use [ParsePKIXPublicKey](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#ParsePKIXPublicKey) directly to parse it. However, Secp256k1 curve is not supported by the default lib. So my solution was to copy the code from the lib and manually get x and y. I then use goethereum crypto lib to get the address and check if point is on the curve.

```go
import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    crypto "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

type publicKeyInfo struct {
    Raw       asn1.RawContent
    Algorithm pkix.AlgorithmIdentifier
    PublicKey asn1.BitString
}
func main() {
    pemData := []byte(`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEjgRz1kswP5KV4diFvYGegDVjeTIABq0a
82r4T41Wz94LDApF9OGyZsUSoQ59gaEVQark4mEQGQqV9HHQzlPavQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`)
    // better to read directly from file:
    // pemData, err := os.ReadFile("your_pub_file.pem") // just pass the file name
    // if err != nil {
    //  fmt.Print(err)
    // }
    block, _ := pem.Decode(pemData)
    if block == nil {
        panic("failed to parse PEM block containing the public key")
    }
    var pki publicKeyInfo
    asn1.Unmarshal(block.Bytes, &pki)
    asn1Data := pki.PublicKey.RightAlign()
    _, x, y := asn1Data[0], asn1Data[1:33], asn1Data[33:]
    fmt.Println("x and y : ", hex.EncodeToString(x), hex.EncodeToString(y))
    x_big := new(big.Int)
    x_big.SetBytes(x)
    y_big := new(big.Int)
    y_big.SetBytes(y)
    pubkey := ecdsa.PublicKey{Curve: crypto.S256(), X: x_big, Y: y_big}
    address := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(pubkey)
    isOnCurve := crypto.S256().IsOnCurve(pubkey.X, pubkey.Y)
    fmt.Println("Is the point on curve ? ", isOnCurve)
    fmt.Println("address: ", address)
}
```

The output:

```bash
x and y :  8e0473d64b303f9295e1d885bd819e80356379320006ad1af36af84f8d56cfde 0b0c0a45f4e1b266c512a10e7d81a11541aae4e26110190a95f471d0ce53dabd
Is the point on curve ?  true
address:  0x7D6bbc553e34C171Ab13fd0251bd496dCC069a1d
```

Comment: Just to add in the context: 
The OID string in this pem file is "1.2.840.10045.2.1" and the supported list is probably from here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/38cfb3be9d486833456276777155980d1ec0823e/src/crypto/x509/x509.go#L520-L539 
Whenever I tried the default ParsePKIXPublicKey it always throws `x509: unsupported elliptic curve`. That's the reason for the manually crafted code.  I'm not sure when they will add new curve